# upsampling multiple time series in one dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

got data like that in a csv

```
id,date,price
A,2020-05-04 15:00:00,1.2
B,2020-05-04 15:05:00,1.3
A,2020-05-04 16:07:00,1.4
B,2020-05-04 16:07:00,1.5
```

so there is a time series for A and another one for B in same DataFrame.
I created dataframe and put index like `df.set_index(["id","date"])`

now I want to upsample to minute so that result corresponds to a csv looking like that:

```
id,date,price
A,2020-05-04 15:00:00,1.2
A,2020-05-04 15:01:00,1.2
...
A,2020-05-04 16:06:00,1.2
A,2020-05-04 16:07:00,1.4
B,2020-05-04 15:05:00,1.3
B,2020-05-04 15:06:00,1.3
...
B,2020-05-04 16:06:00,1.3
B,2020-05-04 16:07:00,1.5
```

but dont get that `df.resample("60S", level ="date").pad()` thing going, getting error that I can only use it for "Datetimeindex but it is Multiindex" when omitting level and putting level getting "Upsampling from level= or on= selection is not supported, use .set_index to explicitly set index to datetime-like" error...

I feel there must be a simple solution...?inst it very common to have multiple instances of a series in one dataset?
For sure I could split dataframe and combine thereafter...
There is also some post using grouper but that to me sounds overly complex, to it sounds like level parameter must be the solution somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) chained with [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
df = df.set_index("date").groupby('id').resample("60S").pad()
print (df)
                       id  price
id date                         
A  2020-05-04 15:00:00  A    1.2
   2020-05-04 15:01:00  A    1.2
   2020-05-04 15:02:00  A    1.2
   2020-05-04 15:03:00  A    1.2
   2020-05-04 15:04:00  A    1.2
                   ..    ...
B  2020-05-04 16:03:00  B    1.3
   2020-05-04 16:04:00  B    1.3
   2020-05-04 16:05:00  B    1.3
   2020-05-04 16:06:00  B    1.3
   2020-05-04 16:07:00  B    1.5

[131 rows x 2 columns]
```

For processing only `price` column use:

```
df1 = df.set_index("date").groupby('id')['price'].resample("60S").pad().reset_index()
print (df1)
    id                date  price
0    A 2020-05-04 15:00:00    1.2
1    A 2020-05-04 15:01:00    1.2
2    A 2020-05-04 15:02:00    1.2
3    A 2020-05-04 15:03:00    1.2
4    A 2020-05-04 15:04:00    1.2
..  ..                 ...    ...
126  B 2020-05-04 16:03:00    1.3
127  B 2020-05-04 16:04:00    1.3
128  B 2020-05-04 16:05:00    1.3
129  B 2020-05-04 16:06:00    1.3
130  B 2020-05-04 16:07:00    1.5

[131 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: awesome, I knew it cant be that hard

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer given by @jezrael will only work where you have unique timestamps in the "date" column. If you have any duplicates, then `.set_index("date")` will complain with `ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit`

I believe the only way to solve this if there are to be duplicates is to handle each `id` separately.